# Using different .cshrc.user files

Tags: linux, gnome, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell, csh

I have two `.cshrc.user` files for two different projects. For example, they set the same environment variables but with different values.

When I'm currently switching between projects, I run a python script which copies in the correct `.cshrc.user` file to my home folder before I open a new terminal window.

Is there a more convenient way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify an rc file for `csh` to invoke after the usual ones (that is, `/etc/csh.{chsrc,login}` and `$HOME/{.cshrc,.login}`) with the `-m` flag. You could keep all the shared configuration in `.cshrc` and move the project-specific things to their own rc files, and just start a new `csh` session from within your existing one whenever you want to work on your project like so:

```
exec csh -m .cshrc.project1
```

This has the added advantage that project-specific variables don't get in the way during your regular shell use. The downside is that you'll need to do this in every new terminal window. How much of a pain that is depends on your workflow.